# Angular patchValue() does not update Ant Design custom form control

Tags: angular, antd, angular-forms

I've created a custom form control so that I can perform API requests to populate the field and hide the complexity from the parent component. The control works as expected except when trying to prepopulate the field. The value is set in the form but does not display in the template. There is also a console log showing that the `ControlValueAccessor` method `writeValue()` is being called, but again the display itself is empty.

The use case is for the U (update/edit) piece of a CRUD webpage.

I've [reproduced the issue with stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zdcj2a?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!